# What would be a good way to pack a huge set of files so that they can be deployed on Azure fast?

Tags: performance, deployment, azure, zip, packaging

My Azure role depends on a huge native library that ships as a set of directories about 700 megabytes total. The library is updates something like once a year. The current solution is that the whole tree is packed into a single .zip file which is then split into chunks and uploaded into Blob Storage. When a role instance starts it downloads the chunks one by one and saves them sequentially into a single file thus restoring the original .zip. Then the .zip is unpacked using Info-ZIP `unzip` program.

Now downloading takes something like 25 seconds but unpacking can take 2-4 minutes and that's not fast enough. I've looked at per-process performance counters and it looks like `unzip.exe` consumes no more than 25 % CPU time so the problem is likely heavy I/O - the .zip has to be read from the disk and then the extracted data needs to be written to the disk. I'm looking for some other approach to packing (and unpacking) the library that would allow for faster deployment.

How could I pack the library so that it unpacks as fast as possible when my code runs on Azure?

Answer (score 1):

A long running installation (even though it's about 5min in your case) is a perfect reason why you would use the VM Role. You build your custom image (containing these libraries), upload it and use that image as an image for your instances. Now if you look at the documentation you should not use the VM Role for production deployments - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg433107

An alternative could be the Cloud Drive. This is a page blob that you mount as an NTFS drive in your instance. The issue you have here is that only a single instance can mount the Cloud Drive (no real support for multiple instances).

What I would suggest:

1. Create a VHD on your local machine containing the required libraries
2. Upload it as a page blob to your storage account
3. Make sure the cache is large enough so it can hold all your files to avoid network latency (More info: [CloudDrive.InitializeCache Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storageclient.clouddrive.initializecache%28v=MSDN.10%29.aspx))
4. For each instance, create a snapshot and mount that snapshot as a Cloud Drive. This is a workaround to be able to use the 'same' Cloud Drive on multiple instances. (More info: [CloudDrive.Snapshot Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.windowsazure.storageclient.clouddrive.snapshot.aspx))

An other solution could be that you download the VHD to a LocalResource and mount it using **diskpart** (in a startup task).

**Note:** I see a VHD file as an alternative way of packaging files.

Comment: Creating a vhd ahead of time, to attach to your running instances, is a great idea, as nothing needs to be unzipped at startup. Creating a page blob snapshot is negligible, time-wise. As long as you're ok with the snapshot being read-only, this solution should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

25% CPU usually means that your box has 4 cores, one of which is used at 100%. Compressing data is usually single-threaded.

So you are CPU bound.

You could zip each chunk individually so you can decompress them individually. Splitting the work like that allows for parallelization. You will likely get 3x-4x speedup from this.

If you need to go even faster you need to look for a faster compression utility like QuickLZ.

Comment: I have a "small" single-core instance.